# What do The Orville's uniform colours indicate?

Tags: the-orville

The crew of the Orville (and the Admiral) wear a wide range of uniform colours including red, orange, blue, green, blue, grey and purple.

[image]

Do we have a *definitive* indication of what these various uniform colours indicate?

Comment: Blue is definitely reserved for primary command, I.e. Captain, 1st officer, and 2nd officer. Red is security. Green is medical. Orange.. So far is helmsman / navigation. The robot science officer doesn't wear a uniform, so we don't know what color he would get (maybe green). Grey... Janitors? Or maybe engineers. And i don't remember seeing purple.

Comment: @JackBNimble - The robot appears to have blue highlights.

Comment: @JackBNimble - That's an awful lot of medical staff. Nearly 15-20%(ish) of the crew?

Comment: Well, it is a sortof parody of StarTrek, and on that medics and science shared the same color. I would guess the same here. We wont know until we see more episodes I guess.

Comment: @JackBNimble - I was hoping for a quote from the show's makers.

Comment: I would've guessed green is science, and medical is a subset of science. Also, I think the engineering guys were wearing orange as well.

Comment: @Valorum Don't forget the reason the chief medical officer requested transfer to the Orville, that could explain the number of medical staff

Comment: That textile technology is more advanced in this future than the Star Trek one. There are at least two more colors available.

Comment: And where is yaphit?

Comment: @Morri - Sick bay, probably.

Comment: @Paul Based on seeing another science officer (green uniform, but with a different badge) in the Ja'loja episode, I believe that you are correct about subsets within sections

Answer (score 20):

### Purple: Admiralty

[image]
[image][image]

We've seen three admirals, Tucker, Ozawa, and Halsey, and all three have purple uniforms, and they all sport the "Command" chest badge.

### Blue: Command

[image]

We see this on Captain Mercer, Commander Kelly Grayson, and Lieutentant Commander Bortus. Again then have the Union icon that denotes command.

### Green: Science

[image]

We see this on Doctor Claire Finn, she has the "science" badge.

***Peter M*** and **Datasaac** have noted there is a non-medical science badge as well, though both show an atom diagram.

### Orange: Engineering

[image]

Both helmsman and those in engineering wear this color and the "two gears"  badge.

### Red: Security

[image]

Lieutenant Alara Kitan wearing a red uniform with a "shield" badge.

### Grey: Enlisted

[image]

Here we see the backs of several grey dressed crewmen. They appear to have colored stripes on their grey uniforms (green and red).

[image]

Here we see (albeit blurry) the grey uniformed crew have the same badges as officers denoting sections (engineering gears, science green, red shield security) with matching color stripes.

Comment: Also, the clearly broad age range of the grey folk seems to rule out cadets (which they would be if it were a mapping to Trek), making enlisted the most likely choice.

Comment: Probably another question, but is there a reason Doctor Finn's green hair matches her uniform?

Comment: Having just seen the 2018 Ja’loja episode, it features [Jayne Tyler](http://orville.wikia.com/wiki/Janel_Tyler) who is a Dark Matter Cartographer.  Jayne sports the green uniform of a science officer, but has a totally different badge to Dr Finn.  This indicates that there are divisions within each section, as speculated in the questions comments.

Comment: Good spot on the grey. However, it seems to make no sense. Colored uniforms are used to allow you to tell at a glance what people you need to pay attention too in a busy and noisy enviornment. So if the yellow guy is waving you know he's not waving to you, but if the red guy is waving... get down! Since enlisted outnumber officers, and they're the ones doing the work that you need to quickly ID, it would be more logical to reverse the color system.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Very little about The Orville is logical.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Looking at the imagine in the question, it appears that officers outnumber enlisted (if grey is indeed enlisted).

Comment: Indeed, which returns to Jack's answer above!

Answer (score 5):

The green science badge, different from the medical badge, although both share the schematic atom.

[image: Character shown wearing green with the science badge]

Answer (score 2):

We have confirmation from the behind-the-scenes book, [*The World of the Orville*](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/The_World_of_the_Orville), what the various uniform colours relate to;

> Fleet uniforms are color-coded. Blue for command, green for medical and sciences, orange for helm, navigation and engineering, red for security.

It also notes that green is associated with a number of named specialisms;

> Medical, Life Sciences, Astronomy, Chemistry, Biology, Exobiology, Mathematics and Computer Sciences

---

A uniform colour-guide was issued with the [2017 press kit](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/2017_press_kits) to promote the show.

It's missing purple and grey, but this seems to be the first  *official* confirmation of the uniform arrangements by the show's makers.

> [image]
>
> **Command Level [Blue]**
> Those in the Command ranks oversee all aspects
> of the ship, with the primary goals of keeping its occupants - and
> those of the Planetary Union - safe.
>
> **Science Level [Green]**
> As an exploratory vessel, The Orville requires
> top-notch scientists to aid in its investigation of the unknown and
> help solve the riddles of the universe
>
> **Medical Bay [Green]**
> With space exploration comes the great unknown, and with it, the risk of injury or disease. Medical Officers aboard The Orville help keep the crew in tip-top shape.
>
> **Engineering Level [Orange]**
> It takes steady hands for the helmsman and
> navigator to steer through supernovas, black holes and asteroid fields - while the engineering officers and maintenance crew work at the speed of light in the heart of the ship.
>
> **Security Level [Red]**
> Intergalactic exploration doesn't come without
> making a few enemies. Security Officers protect The Orville against
> its intergalactic foes, such as the dreaded Krill.