# Is the Orville's Dann inspired by Babylon 5's Narn?

Tags: aliens, inspiration, babylon-5, the-orville, influences

I haven't watched *The Orville*, but while scrolling through [a three-year-old answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175663/31394) I noticed a picture of an alien whom I quickly identified as the character called [Dann](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/Dann). The reason why his appearance jumped out at me is that he looks (IMO) remarkably like the [Narn](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Narn) species of *Babylon 5*:

[image: Dann]
[image: Na'Toth]

Both alien species have large hairless heads, prominent large leopard-like spots all over their craniums, and deep eyes sunken behind those thick layers of prosthetics. I'm [not the only person to have noticed this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheOrville/comments/b5px1h/finally_realized_who_dann_reminds_me_of/), but I couldn't find much info about it beyond random forum discussions.

### **Is Dann's alien species inspired by the Narn?**

<sub>The most conclusive answer would be a quote from someone involved with *The Orville*, but I doubt such a thing is available or I would have found it already. Other acceptable evidence might include (for example) an analysis of other references to older (non-Star Trek) scifi in *The Orville*, character analysis of Dann to see if he bears any resemblance to Narn characters from B5, or knowledge about B5 fans among *The Orville* creators. But please try to build up a compelling argument, not just something like "the Orville showrunner was a fan of B5, so it must be!"</sub>

Comment: Heh.. sweetness...